# Posting to Facebook via Website Application - Internal Server Error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, runtime-error, facebook-php-sdk

I am using the following code to get a User's posts, with APP_ID, and APP_SECRET replaced with the appropriate fields.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',]);

$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();

$permissions = ['user_posts']; // optionnal

try {
if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
$accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
} else {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
}
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {

if (isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
} else {
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

    // OAuth 2.0 client handler
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
    $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);

    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;

    $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
}

// validating the access token
try {
    $request = $fb->get('/me');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    if ($e->getCode() == 190) {
        unset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
        $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/', $permissions);
        echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
        exit;
    }
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

// getting all posts published by user
try {
    $posts_request = $fb->get('/me/posts?limit=500');
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

$total_posts = array();
$posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge();
if($fb->next($posts_response)) {
    $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
    $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);
    while ($posts_response = $fb->next($posts_response)) {  
        $response_array = $posts_response->asArray();
        $total_posts = array_merge($total_posts, $response_array);  
    }
    print_r($total_posts);
} else {
    $posts_response = $posts_request->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    print_r($posts_response);
}

// Now you can redirect to another page and use the access token from $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']
} else {
 $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAMESPACE/', $permissions);
 echo "<script>window.top.location.href='".$loginUrl."'</script>";
```

}

When I run it locally on command line (php post.php), I get the following:

```
<script>window.top.location.href='https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?client_id=843019182480437&state=bb8b088f64641baed7d1e4de734ad19b&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.1.2&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2FAPP_NAMESPACE%2F&scope=user_posts
```

Which means the syntax is correct. When I go to the link I get the following notification by Facebook:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

I have set the Website URL to the appropriate value. When I try to access post.php from my server I get an internal server error.

Has anyone else experienced this before?

Comment: You need to fill in `Valid OAuth Redirect URIs` under Settings->Advanced as well.

Comment: @CBroe now I get: Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Comment: @CBroe the browser still returns 500 Internal error